# How to use a dynamically created UpdatePanel on .NET

Tags: vb.net, updatepanel

I have the following code:

```
Dim newUp As New UpdatePanel
newUp.ID = "upFlux"

Dim newLbl As New Label
newLbl.ID = "lblFlux"

newUp.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(newLbl)
```

ok, now in another part of my code (another method) i want to get this update panel and work on it. I want something like:

```
Dim up As new UpdatePanel("upFlux")
up.someCodeHere
```

what can i do?

ty in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you are done creating a new `UpdatePanel` and adding the label, you should add it to the page

```
Page.Controls.Add(newUp)
```

and later on you should be able to reference the `UpdatePanel`  like this

```
Dim up as UpdatePanel = TryCast(Page.FindControl("upFlux"), UpdatePanel)
```